# 'list index out of range' from subprocess stdout

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

Whetever I do, I get this error when trying to print anything from 'ip_macAddr' using an index.
Type is 'list' so I don't get why. The only explanation I have is that there's some type of caracter coming from the stdout of that subprocess that's messing things up.

Also I tried converting to string with no different result.

At this point I have ne clue.
Thanks for your help!

**Code**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import sys
import subprocess
import os

IP_NETWORK = '192.168.254.10'
IP_DEVICE = '192.168.254.194'

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', IP_NETWORK], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    # print(line)

    if not line:
        break
    connected_ip = line.decode('utf-8').split()[3].replace(':','')

    proc2 = subprocess.Popen(['ip', 'neigh', 'show', 'to', connected_ip], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    ip_macAddr = proc2.stdout.readline().decode('utf-8').split()

    
    print(connected_ip)
    # print(type(ip_macAddr))
    print(ip_macAddr[0])
```

**Error**

`IndexError: list index out of range`

*edit 1*

The output of `print(ip_macAddr)` would be: `['192.168.254.10', 'dev', 'wlp61s0', 'lladdr', '88:88:a1:b2:c3:88', 'REACHABLE']`

*edit 2*

`print(type(ip_macAddr))` returns `<class 'list'>`

*edit 3*
**Traceback**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./device-connected-to-network.py", line 34, in <module>
    print(ip_macAddr[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This would happen using ANY index and I also tried using:
 `print(ip_macAddr[0])` or `ip_macAddr = proc2.stdout.split()[0]`

Again; same result using ANY index # and `print(type(ip_macAddr))` returns type 'list'.

Another exemple;

The output of `print(ip_macAddr)`is `['192.168.254.10', 'dev', 'wlp61s0', 'lladdr', '74:83:c2:d2:a4:12', 'REACHABLE']`.

So, if I do (in another file) - using index #4:

```
a = ['192.168.254.10', 'dev', 'wlp61s0', 'lladdr', '11:22:a1:b2:c3:33', 'REACHABLE']

print(type(a))
print(a[4])
```

The output is:

```
<class 'list'>
11:22:a1:b2:c3:33
```

So works as expected in this context, but not within the actual program.

Comment: What is the output of `print(connected_ip)`? If it is an empty list, then `ip_macAddr[0]` will generate a list index out of range.

Comment: Thanks for asking @HaiVu, I undated the original post.
The index I am tying to pull if from ```ip_macAddr``` though.

Comment: In the future, please always include the full traceback.

Answer (score 1):

`split()[3]` will fail with an `IndexError` on any line which has less than four whitespace-separated fields.

A common fix is to simply skip lines with fewer fields.

Similarly, if `ip` produces an empty string, splitting it produces an empty list, which you can't get the first element of.

You can also simplify your code by passing in `text=True`, and use `subprocess.run()` where you don't particularly need `Popen()`. I have also removed unused `import`s.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7
import subprocess

IP_NETWORK = '192.168.254.10'
IP_DEVICE = '192.168.254.194'

proc = subprocess.Popen(['ping', IP_NETWORK],
     stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)

while True:
    line = proc.stdout.readline()
    # print(line)

    if not line:
        break
    fields = line.split()

    if len(fields) < 4:
        continue

    connected_ip = fields[3].replace(':','')

    proc2 = subprocess.run(
        ['ip', 'neigh', 'show', 'to', connected_ip],
        capture_output=True, text=True)
    result = proc2.stdout

    if not result:
        continue

    ip_macAddr = result[0]

    print(connected_ip)
    # print(type(ip_macAddr))
    print(ip_macAddr)
```

Even better, trap and report any exceptions.

```
try:
    proc2 = subprocess.run(
        ['ip', 'neigh', 'show', 'to', connected_ip],
        capture_output=True, text=True,
        check=True)  # important
    result = proc2.stdout
except CalledProcessError as exc:
    print('`ip\' for', connected_ip, 'failed:', exc)
    continue
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but it's the output of ```proc2``` that I am trying to access via the index (4, in this situation).

With you proposition I still get the same error. :/

Let's say: ```proc2 = subprocess.run(['ip', 'neigh', 'show', 'to', connected_ip], capture_output=True, text=True) ip_macAddr = proc2.stdout.split(',')[4]```

Whatever the index, the same error. And If ```[4]``` is removed, as stated in the original post, the output is:

```['192.168.254.10', 'dev', 'wlp61s0', 'lladdr', '88:88:a1:b2:c3:88', 'REACHABLE']```

Which to me looks legit

Comment: I wish I could just pipe it to | awk '{print $5}'  and call it a day, lol...

Comment: So again, please provide a full traceback.

Comment: Uplated answer. Maybe print a warning when `ip` produces empty output if you want to debug further.

Comment: Actually probably add `check=True` to the `run` call and print the error when it fails.

Comment: I updated the original post with trackback and further exemples.
Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything to disprove the deduction that the `ip` command returns empty output for *some* inputs, whereas you apparently have tested with others. Or maybe you are running from e.g. a `cron` job or something where `ip` is not even on the `PATH`? I'll repeat the suggestion to trap and report any exceptions.